# Android fragment tab host + viewpager swipe?

Tags: android, fragment, swipe

I currently have a fragment tab host, made by this tutorial
http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

The only difference is that I'm using this inside a fragment.
So I have a fragment with the tabs, each tab has another fragment..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment class

```
public class AddServiceFragment extends Fragment {




    public AddServiceFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_service, container, false);
        FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);


        String[] tabs = new String[]{"text1", "text2"};
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(tabs[0], null),
                MedicalHistoryFragment.class, null);


        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(tabs[1], null),
                MedicalHistoryFragment.class, null);

            return view;
    }
```

This works, I can see my tabs.
Now I want to implement a viewpager, in order to be able to swipe left or right.

I've read this from the android developer page
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

But I can't figure out, where should I put my viewpager?
I want my fragment to be independent of my activity...

Answer (score 11):

TabHost doesn't provide ViewPager support.
Also, I suggest you to not use TabHost – this is old style.
Use [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)

Look this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/pboos/4535406).

**UPD:**
I add some code, for case, if this Gist be deleted;

MainActivity.java

```
package ch.pboos.android.sample.viewpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter());
    }

    public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

        public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter() {
            super(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PageFragment.create(position + 1);
        }
    }

    public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

        private int mPage;

        public static PageFragment create(int page) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
            PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (without PagerTabStrip)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

activity_main_2.xml (with PagerTabStrip)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#000"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

fragment_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

getPageTitle

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Page " + (position + 1);
}
```

**UPD 2**
With Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter());
    }

    public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;

        public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter() {
            super(getSupportFragmentManager());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PageFragment.create(position + 1);
        }
    }

    public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

        private int mPage;

        public static PageFragment create(int page) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
            PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: There is no huge difference between Activity and Fragment, in this case. Just instead #onCreate() method you should implement #onCreateView() to inflate view from layout resource and #onActivityCreated() (or onViewCreated()) for init some views. I edited my question with code snippet of how it can be implemented. Please, check it.

Comment: Can you tell me from where you know that TabHost is old-style? I am already searching the whole day about this topic (tabs with fragments) and it was incredibly painful. Developer docs tells you about ViewPager for sliding, about using ActionBar tabs, AndroidStudio that latter is deprecated and provides TabHost in UI designer (Besides all the more or less hacked solutions on SO etc). Why can all these classes exist without any documentation? How can anybody expect that a majority of apps implement a not deprecated and proper interface? Sorry, last questions are of course rhetorical..

Comment: @TiBo TabHost is old-style because it has no sliding feature. Change tabs on slide is a good UX, that used in many applications, so it got usual. When user see tabs, he expects that he can change tab with swipe. I should say, that TabHost is not deprecated, but I think it's better to use newer alternatives. ||| What classes exist without any documentation?

Comment: I meant documentation in the way of explaining them in the training or guides sections... Is it also possible to enable the classic TabHost style?

Comment: I don't understand what do you complain about. Old-style docs for tabs: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html, new-material-style docs: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage. And I didn't understand what 'classic TabHost style' is. And why do you need some 'classic' style, rather than new material (or at least holo) style

Comment: With classic I meant that you could have a PagerStripTab with Old/New-material-style of TabHost. I why just wondering why this class which you considered as "new-style" is not mentioned in the docs (at least I couln't find them..)

Answer (score 1):

use the following solution i have put the view page like below.. and my work done..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I think he'd like to have TabHost+ViewPager 'working' together, but not just putting ViewPager somewhere inside TabHost.

Comment: He is not sure to put where viewpager inside the tab host. Thats why i have displayed this code as i have implemented in my project and it worked well..

Comment: @ArpitPatel How do you implemented it? Can you show some sample?

Comment: @ArpitPatel can you show implementation code of it or little bit idea

Comment: actually this is very old style nowadays.. User material tabs from [here](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the viewpager as a library.

First thing you need to import viewpager project to the eclipse workspace.
[ I think you are modifying the project :Tabhost example]

so right click your Tabhost example project thn build path -> configure build path..
thn click Android ...when you click android you can see 2 section Project build Target & Library.So in Library you can add the viewpager Library.

Comment: No, sorry, your answer is wrong, and I use Android Studio by the way.

Comment: you can include it only via maven.
So If you need to add library folder in android studio and include it in app.gradle.file.
 library.gradle:-
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to include viewpager library to the project ,you should import the library
"Existing Project” to your current one.

Step 1:-Download source code from GitHub.(https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Step2 :-In your Android Studio Project: 
File -> Project Structure -> add (+ symbol) -> Import Existing Project. Import just the folder called ”library”, not the entire project (leave the import options as Android Studio suggests).

step 3:-If the "compileSdkVersion" specified in your build.gradle doesn’t match with the one specified in the Android-ViewPagerIndicator project, change the second one. 
The same apply with any other property, such as "minSdkVersion" or even the current support library.

Step 4:-Add Android-ViewPagerIndicator project as a dependency to your build.gradle module:
    dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
     }

Step 5:- Sync project with gradle files.