# Add Tabs inside a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I want to show just two tabs inside a fragment. Tabs are fragments too.
Whats the best way.

I tried this ([Android fragment tab host + viewpager swipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381850/android-fragment-tab-host-viewpager-swipe)) method, when I go to this fragment first, both tabs seems to work fine. however when I go back and load that fragment again, tabs are empty.

How can I improve this or what other methods are there?

Thanks

Comment: you can go for Fragment Activity in this case, it will work perfectly.

Comment: but I used fragment transitions my current architecture, can I do that with Fragment activity. I mean replace fragment with fragment activity