# Swipe TabWidget on swipe of viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-tab-host

I'm writing an application where using FragmentTabHost. Each of host child contain ViewPager as Child. Here I want to move control to second TabWidget if user swipe from last page of ViewPager of First TabWidget.

Example: So like **Recharge** Tab has it's own ViewPager kind of implementation and when it move from last ViewPager page, control get swiped to **Electronics** Tab. How can I achieve this !

[image]

Any suggestion !

Comment: have you checked this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381850/android-fragment-tab-host-viewpager-swipe

Comment: @Ajit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26382071/2624806) I need to check..also in my case I have used Fixed **FragmentTabHost** with 3 TabWidget, so not sure how **PagerTabStrip** can help here.

Comment: you mean have only three fragments(Fixed) Right?

Comment: Yes..Ajit using FragmentTabHost with 3 TabWidget as mention in previous comment.

Comment: for More clarification, you want if user swipe from third page it should come to first page right?

Comment: nna..it should work exactly in same manner no round robin. So say after Right Swipe if control move to Second Tab then on Left Swipe it should get back to First Tab. Same for 2nd and 3rd Tab transition. Got idea!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92219/discussion-between-ajit-and-shubh).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom viewpager. If the child viewpager is at the end, scroll the parent

```
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    if(v != this && v instanceof ViewPager) {
        int currentItem = ((ViewPager) v).getCurrentItem();
        int countItem = ((ViewPager) v).getAdapter().getCount();
        if((currentItem==(countItem-1) && dx<0) || (currentItem==0 && dx>0)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
}
```

Comment: sunny, in this case if view pager has reached to last page then you will no more able to get scroll event...so not sure how ur solution will work in that case!